How would I add a VS Code-style line counter?
I'm attempting to create a Visual Studio Code extension that counts the number of lines in the currently open file. However, I've hit a roadblock in implementing the line counting functionality.
I tried going through each line of text one by one and counting them using a basic loop, but it was really slow and often gave the wrong count, especially with big files. Then I thought about using regular expressions to find line breaks, but that got messy with multiline text and comments, so it wasn't reliable. I even looked into using existing libraries or modules that could do the counting for me, but none of them fit smoothly into my custom text editor project.
Here is my code (I removed my line counting logic):
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTextEdit, QAction, QFileDialog, QVBoxLayout, QWidget


    class Notepad(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Notepad")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 600, 400)

        self.central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.setContentsMargins(10, 10, 10, 10)  # Add margin around the central widget
        layout.setSpacing(10)  # Add spacing between the menu bar and text box
        self.central_widget.setLayout(layout)

        self.text_edit = QTextEdit()
        self.text_edit.setStyleSheet(
            "QTextEdit { background-color: #282828; color: purple; border: none; }"
            "QTextEdit:hover { background-color: #282828; }"
        )
        layout.addWidget(self.text_edit)

        self.central_widget.setStyleSheet(
            "background-color: #282828;"  # Set the background color of the central widget
        )

        self.create_menu()

    def create_menu(self):
        main_menu = self.menuBar()
        main_menu.setStyleSheet(
            "QMenuBar { background-color: #1d1f21; color: #FFFFFF; }"
        )
        file_menu = main_menu.addMenu("File")
        file_menu.setStyleSheet(
            "QMenu { background-color: #1d1f21; color: #FFFFFF; }"
        )

        save_action = QAction("Save", self)
        save_action.triggered.connect(self.save_file)
        file_menu.addAction(save_action)

        open_action = QAction("Open", self)
        open_action.triggered.connect(self.open_file)
        file_menu.addAction(open_action)

    def save_file(self):
        file_path, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Save File", "", "Text Files (*.txt)")
        if file_path:
            with open(file_path, "w") as file:
                text = self.text_edit.toPlainText()
                file.write(text)

    def open_file(self):
        file_path, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open File", "", "Text Files (*.txt)")
        if file_path:
            with open(file_path, "r") as file:
                text = file.read()
                self.text_edit.setPlainText(text)


    if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Notepad()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

https://ibb.co/JsdWgSL the intended functionality

For this purpose, using QTextEdit is normally discouraged. Use QPlainTextEdit instead, which is more aimed for large text content and provides better performance.
